# Add Custom Control To ComboBox

Tags: combobox, controls

Hi All
I create a custom User control and I want this custom control placed inside a combo box.
I'm using this code:

```
public class UserControlComboBox : ComboBox, IMessageFilter
{
    public readonly NimaDatePickerUC.MiladiNimaDatePickerUC UserControl = new NimaDatePickerUC.MiladiNimaDatePickerUC();

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if ((m.Msg == 0x0201) || (m.Msg == 0x0203))
        {
            if (DroppedDown)
                HideUserControl();
            else
                ShowUserControl();
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        // intercept mouse events 
        if ((m.Msg >= 0x0200) && (m.Msg <= 0x020A))
        {
            if (this.UserControl.RectangleToScreen(this.UserControl.DisplayRectangle).Contains(Cursor.Position))
            {
                // clicks inside the user control, handle normally
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                // clicks outside the user controlcollapse it. 
                if ((m.Msg == 0x0201) || (m.Msg == 0x0203))
                    this.HideUserControl();
                return true;
            }
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public new bool DroppedDown
    {
        get { return this.UserControl.Visible; }
    }

    protected void ShowUserControl()
    {
        if (!this.Visible)
            return;

        this.UserControl.Anchor = this.Anchor;
        this.UserControl.BackColor = this.BackColor;
        this.UserControl.Font = this.Font;
        this.UserControl.ForeColor = this.ForeColor;

        // you can be cleverer than this if you need to 
        this.UserControl.Top = this.Bottom;
        this.UserControl.Left = this.Left;
        this.UserControl.Width = Math.Max(this.UserControl.Width, this.Width);


        this.Parent.Controls.Add(this.UserControl);
        this.Parent.Controls[0].BringToFront();
        this.UserControl.Visible = true;
        this.UserControl.BringToFront();

        base.OnDropDown(EventArgs.Empty);

        // start listening for clicks 
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    protected void HideUserControl()
    {
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);

        base.OnDropDownClosed(EventArgs.Empty);
        this.UserControl.Visible = false;
        this.Parent.Controls.Remove(this.UserControl);

        // you probably want to replace this with something more sensible 
        this.Text = this.UserControl.Text;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.UserControl.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

this code works well but if I'm using Combo Box inside a CONTAINER and the container smaller than comboBox size+My Custom control ,my custom control does not appear well and appear beneath the group box.
How I can show my custom control in front of all controls and containers?

Comment: Is this a control for .NET 3.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

This may seem intuitive but have you tried the

```
[controlname].BringToFront();
```

also found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: You may want to look up how to make your control top level then. It seems like that's what you're trying to do.